# PHP normalize multidimensional array

Tags: php

want to normalize an array and need help.

Array i have:

```
$myArr = array(
  array(
    array(
      array("id" => 1)
    )
  ),
  array("id" => 2),
  array("id" => 3),
  array(
    array(
     "id" => 4)
    )
);
```

Array i want to have:

```
 $myArr = array(
  array("id" => 1),
  array("id" => 2),
  array("id" => 3),
  array("id" => 4)
);
```

My idea to solve that prob is calling a recursive method, which is not working yet:

```
function myRecArrFunc(&myarr){
  $output = [];

  foreach{$myarr as $v}{
      if(!isset{$v["id"]){
       $output[] = myRecArrFunc($v);
      } else{
        $output[] = $v;
      }
  }      

  return $output
}
```

Currently the output of the function is the same as the input. Someone has an idea what have to be done?

Comment: Your code has several syntax issues. A missing dollar before `myarr`, a loose brace, missing parentheses around function argument for `isset`, a missing semi-colon near the end....

Answer (score 4):

Yould use [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php):

```
$result = [];
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($myArr)) as $k => $v) {
    $result[] = [$k => $v];
}
```

Or even simpler, [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($myArr, function($v, $k) use (&$result) {
    $result[] = [$k => $v];
});
```

#### About your code

Your code had at least 5 syntax errors, but ignoring those, you need to take into account that the recursive call will return an array, with potentially many id/value pairs. So you need to concatenate that array to your current results. You can use `array_merge` to make the code work:

```
function myRecArrFunc(&$myarr){
    $output = [];

    foreach($myarr as $v){
        if(!isset($v["id"])){
            $output = array_merge($output, myRecArrFunc($v));
        } else{
            $output[] = $v;
        }
    }      
    return $output;
}
```